# GORM select with join

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, grails-orm

I have trouble with GORM in grails. I have two relationships, that look like this:

```
Company

static hasMany = [
            users:User,
]
---------
User
// no mention about entity Company
```

I need to get all the companies that are connected with a certain user.

```
    User user =  springSecurityService.currentUser

def results = Company.executeQuery("select c from Company c join User u where u.id = ${user.id}")
```

SQL syntax of what I need looks like this:  `Select * from Company C join User u on u.company_id=c.id where u.id=user.id.`

My error is: `Path expected for join!`

In database a new join table was created, it's name is `company_user`. Any idea how to write this simple select?

Comment: select c from Company c join c.users u where u.id = ${user.id}"

Comment: Thank you @vahid. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
User user = springSecurityService.currentUser
def results = Company.executeQuery(
        "from Company c join c.users u where u.id = ?", [user.id])
```